# Alternative to jQuery livequery plugin?

Tags: jquery, livequery

I need to check when an element is alive, I'm doing:

```
$('#obj').livequery(function() { ... });
```

How can I do it with live method or another way?

Comment: Is it something you're generating dynamically (more than once?) or is it present on your page when it's loaded? (i.e. can you just use `$(document).ready(...);`?)

Comment: i'll generate this '#obj' with javascript then it's dynamically

Comment: idk why but when i do fadeIn() in some element, the livequery plugin won't work cuz it i want to find a new alternative.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but for the record, here my 5 cents:

---

An alternative to `livequery` is to use a `Publish/Subscribe` approach with for example this implementation 
[jQuery Tiny Pub/Sub: A really, really, REALLY tiny pub/sub implementation for jQuery.](https://gist.github.com/661855)

I use it, for example, in this way:

```
// inform of DOM change (mostly through AJAX)
$.publish("/table/loaded");

// re-execute plugin
$.subscribe("/table/loaded", function(e, data) {
    $("#my_id input[name='date']").datepicker();
});
```

+info : [Understanding the Publish/Subscribe Pattern for Greater JavaScript Scalability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh201955.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If it is your code that is adding the element to the DOM, then run your code on it when you create it:

```
$('body').append('<div id="obj">some new object</div>');

var obj = $('#obj');

obj.runSomeCode();
```

...or you can even do it before it is appended:

```
var obj = $('<div id="obj">some new object</div>');

obj.runSomeCode();

obj.appendTo('body');
```

Comment: Well, as an alternative to using livequery, you could run the function yourself when you fade the element into the page.

Comment: @Rapososoo: This is an alternative to using livequery. If you don't want livequery to do it automatically, you need to code it manually, which is a better practice anyway IMO.

Comment: The problem is there are multiple clicks that create the same elements. Livequery is great because you focus on was created instead of who created it.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the livequery plug-in you might look at the $.whenLive jQuery plugin:

$.whenLive allows you to track the DOM tree insertion of one or more elements.

http://bitcubby.com/tracking-the-insertion-of-javascript-components-into-the-dom/

Here is an example from that page:

```
var widget = $("<div>I am a nobody. Nobody is perfect. Therefore, I am perfect.</div>");
$(widget).onLive(function() {
    // Awesomesauce.
    var height = $(this).height();
    var width = $(this).width();
});
$("body").append(widget);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but I'm astonished there is no answer as it's simple. You have to use [on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) and attach the event to a parent or body. Ex :

```
$('#obj').livequery('click', function() { ... });
$('#obj').livequery(function() { ... });
```

become

```
$('body').on('click', '#obj', function() { ... });
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted','#obj', function() { ... });
```

note that DOMNodeInserted is IE9+